# Is there are similar method to .get() but one returning a jQuery object instead of a DOM one?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if the people over at jQuery implemented an alternative method to [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/), as in one that returns a jQuery object instead of a DOM node.

This way, I don't have to

1. wrap the object retrieved using the `.get()` method with an additional `$()` call and
2. write my own jQuery plugin in order to provide that functionality.

I especially don't want to do #2 because I will pretty much be reinventing the wheel, when a functionality already exists.

Comment: Why do you not want to use option 1? It's surely "standard" way to get objects "jQuery"'d?

Comment: @RemarkLima: Because it makes the code ugly/less readable - and not necessary in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use .eq(index), which returns a jquery instance. For example

```
var mycoll = $("div.myDivs")
var firstElementOfCollection = mycoll.eq(0);
```

or as ThiefMaster pointed out in his comment below, these will work as well (and are potentially nicer depending what you are doing :))

```
$("div.myDivs:eq(0)");
$("div.myDivs:first");
```

Comment: OMG I'm such an idiot. +1 Probably worth pointing out to the OP that this will be no more efficient than `$(obj[index])` (and probably the teensiest bit less so, not that it will matter).

Comment: or `$("div.myDivs:eq(0)")` or `$("div.myDivs:first")`

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Yeah, but the question implies you're starting with an existing jQuery object.